# Synonym for force-feed?

Tags: synonyms

I can't find one anywhere and can't think of one either, but this is a clever group and maybe someone has a synonym for force-feed, in the sense not of forcible indoctrination, but physically forcing someone to eat something.

Answer (score 7):

> **gavage** (noun)
>   the administration of food or drugs by force, especially to an animal, typically through a tube leading down the throat to the stomach.

<sup>(*New Oxford American Dictionary*)</sup>

Comment: Oh fantastic! I will accept in a couple of minutes. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Yuck! (or 'excellent!' if you're passed out in the hospital)

Comment: I noticed this is from the French, _gaver_, "to force-feed." Is there an equivalent verb form in English?

Comment: I'm quite partial to *gavage*. It just has that *je ne c'est quoi*.

Comment: +1, extremely nice word. Could we possibly add in a guide on the pronunciation?

Answer (score 4):

You could use the verb **cram**, which in addition to its more common meanings is used to describe the process of force-feeding Geese to produce Foie Gras (Source: [FAO](http://www.fao.org/DOCREP/005/Y4359E/y4359e0d.htm)).

<sup>(A horrible thing to do to an animal, I think, so maybe it would generally have a negative connotation when used in the sense of **force-feeding**.)</sup>