# Is there a word that means force feeding someone music?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word which is more akin to force feeding as opposed to being subjected to music as a child, say.

**EDIT**

With respect the the analogy to food, I do not mean literally force-fed as it ducks or geese, and I don't mean force-fed as would be the case for medical reasons.

This is a sentence that makes sense of it:

> As a child, I was force-fed sprouts, even though I didn't like them.

Here, you can image a child sat at the table looking at something they didn't to eat it and being "force-fed" in that they were forced to eat it, through, say, not letting them leave the table. More "forced to eat". I'm sure you agree this is not a case of being "subjected to" in the sense that it is not endured.

I wish to represent this concept with music. Not that a particular style of music was played all the time:

> There was only ever jazz played in the house

That would be subjected to.

> My dad taped headphones to my head and played jazz

That would be literal.

> My parents ________ me jazz.

That is the musical version of the sprouts example with food. A parent might say:

> One more song and we can go out.

or

> You have to listen to this one it's great.

or

> This is the best bit, don't go away.

Comment: Do you mean s/th like _stimulative_?

Comment: Please see the checklist in the [tag info](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) for help with how to write this sort of question. We need **a lot** more information.

Comment: There seem to be few synonyms for 'force-feed' according to [this thread](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29661/synonym-for-force-feed); synonyms for 'force-feed music' would be even less expected.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I have fleshed it out with examples. I hope it meets the required standards now.

Comment: I think it's a reasonable question, I have voted to reopen (though not sure whether community votes can override mod actions). I suspect, however, there is no satisfactory answer. Maybe there's something in the transcript for A Clockwork Orange during the "forced viewing" scene which could be adapted.

Comment: I don't feel the situations are quite analogous, because if music is playing, there is no way to shut your ears to it (though I've tried to on plenty of occasions). It's sounds like jazz was *inflicted* on you as a child, or you were *bombarded* by jazz. Either way, I hope it's not affected you *too* much in your later life. ;)

Comment: @jonlarby the context is that someone has

Comment: @DanBron Yes: five votes on a question work both ways. A mod (or gold-badge) vote is worth five votes; it can be undone as normal.

Comment: It seems a bit ironic that a question about being force-fed music is *on hold*.

Comment: I like suggestions from @JonLarby - if you want something stronger, why not just use *tortured with*?  Or even *my ears were saturated with*.

Comment: Does "rickroll" count?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Force-feed](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/force%E2%80%93feed) is often used metaphorically as well as literally, as the second definition in Merriam Webster shows. Googling "force-fed jazz" comes up with lots of examples, so it seems an unfortunately common phenomenon.

Comment: Yeah, I think that "force fed" is quite appropriate for this situation.  It's readily understood and conveys a degree of coercion.

Answer (score 1):

[***ram down someone's throat***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ram-down-someone-s-throat):  ram /force something down someone's throat, Informal. to force someone to agree to or accept (something).

*(dictionary.com)*

> My parents **rammed** jazz **down my throat**.

This is similar to force-feed, but more effective.

Answer (score 1):

I propose a new word: *I got* **Kenny G'ed** *in the elevator last night.*

**Kenny G** is an American clarinetist/saxophonist. He is the biggest-selling instrumental musician of the modern era whose clarinet-pieces are ubiquitous, almost soporific pieces of piped *Musak* we cannot escape from almost every time we ride an elevator, shop in an upscale mall or when left hanging on the end of a phone awaiting what seems like an eternity to be put through to a *live* human-voice. Evidently we are not so much bombarded as fed subliminally with what passes as a 'musical' experience. (Wikipedia-in-part)

**Musak:** "Elevator music (also know as Muzak, piped music, or lift music) is the name given to a type of instrumental music, that is commonly played through speakers in elevators, shopping-malls, department stores...telephone systems..." [and the like]. (Wikipedia)

Comment: I was about to cheekily suggest U2 (from the whole iPhone débâcle), but Kenny G is actually better.